# How to remove custom view from invisible cell in collection view

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am trying to change color of selected custom view in collection view. I am using didSelectItem and didDeselectItem method of collection view for the same.

I am facing error when i am going to change invisible cell in collectionview.

Visible cell of collection view is perfectly working

My code is below

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = colCellSize.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! colSizeDetails
    cell.viewDetails.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
    cell.lblSize.textColor = UIColor.white
}


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let cell = colCellSize.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! colSizeDetails
    cell.viewDetails.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
    cell.viewDetails.layer.borderColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
    cell.lblSize.textColor = UIColor.gray
    cell.viewDetails.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
}
```

Comment: what's the error says? please post the error log

Comment: Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value  -- no error log display.  getting nil index path

Comment: the error indicates that you are unwrapping an optional value which is initially has nil value. you did not provide where you initialize invisible cell and when you deinit it. please provide more code snippets.

Answer (score 0):

This line is wrong:

```
let cell = colCellSize.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! colSizeDetails
```

Here, you are casting the `cell` as a `colSizeDetails`. The `colSizeDetails` should be it's own class with a subclass of `UICollectionViewCell`. Your class names should never start with a lowercase letter. You need to change your class name to `ColSizeDetails` and then re-write that line with the capital letter. This may be the issue as I cannot see you force unwrapping anymore optionals

Comment: colSizeDetails is the name of the collectionview.and i used it for configure custom cell of collectionview